# Should I use multiple goals to track conversions of multiple versions of home page?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a WordPress site. I have created 4 different versions of the home page, and created a Google experiment to equally distribute traffic between the 5 pages (including the original home page). I want to track that users entered their email, and clicked signup. After signup, they are redirected to a thank you page.

Now, the flow from 3 pages is - signup and redirect. On the other 2 pages, user is given an option of "Find More", taken to a page where the user can signup and redirected to the same thank you page.

I have created a goal, with destination URL being the thank you page, and original home page the first required step. Is this sufficient?

How should I track the signups? Eventually, I want a report which can show me number of visits on each variation and number of signups from each variation.

Answer (score 1):

Defining one goal is fine.   You don't need separate goals for each page.

What you do need to do is tag the traffic that lands on these pages.   There are a couple ways to do it:

#### Campaigns

If this is traffic that is coming in a different site, have it land on these pages with `utm` parameters in the URL.   Use the [Google Analytics URL builder](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) to build a URL with the proper parameters.   Then the traffic will appear in the "Aquisition -> Campaigns" report and you will be able to view it differently by the different utm parameters you used for each page.

#### Experiments

If this is traffic that is originating on your site, you'll want to use the [Google Analytics experiments](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/experiments-overview) feature.  This allows you to create different versions of a page, serve them up randomly to whoever visits this page, and track how your goals perform against the different versions.